# ajax form issue: cannot get data from a select multiple

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

My problem I think is simple (but I am really simple), I am not using jquery or any other plugin just pure JavaScript and PhP.
I have a simple form with a select field in which multiple items can be selected such as :

```
<form id="test" name="test">
<input type="hidden" id="norman" value="bates"/>
<select multiple="multiple" name="fred[]" id="fred[]">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="test" onclick="callAHAH('POST','my-page.php','container','loading...','modify-user')"/>
```

The callAHAH is the javaScript function that wraps up the data for the Ajax, the function is:

```
function callAHAH(method,url, pageElement, callMessage,form_name){
  //window.location = url;

//document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = callMessage;
try{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* ff */
}
catch(e){
    try{
        req = new ActiveObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); /* some ie */
    }
    catch(e){
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); /*other ie */
        }
        catch(e){
            req = false;
        }
    }
}
req.onreadystatechange = function(){responseAHAH(pageElement);};
 var build_url=window.location.origin;
  var url = "aj_scripts/"+url;
 if(build_url=="http://localhost:8080"){        
    url=build_url+"/pitd_outer/pitd/"+url;
 }
// Check request status
if(method=='POST'){
    req.open("POST",url,true);
  // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var the_data="";

  ///
  var the_form=document.getElementById(form_name);
 //alert(form_name);
for (var i=0;i<the_form.length;i++){
      var the_type = the_form.elements[i].type;
      var value;
      if(the_type !="button"){
          if(the_type =="checkbox"){
                value = the_form.elements[i].checked

             // alert("the array name is: "+the_array_name+" and it is checked:"+checked);
          }else{

                value=the_form.elements[i].value;
          }
        var id= the_form.elements[i].id;     
        the_data+=id;
        the_data+="="+value+"&";
      }     
  }      
  the_data=the_data.substring(0,the_data.length-1);//removing the last & symbol  

// alert(the_data);
  req.send(the_data);       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter
}else if(method=="GET"){
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.send(null);
}
}
```

The JS handler has been working fine until I try and select multiple items and then the code only returns either the first or the last selected item.

I understand that the form is sending an array but I cannot seem to get the code to correctly test for an array I tried

```
var array_test=Array.isArray(the_form.elements[i]);
               alert("array test:"+array_test);
```

But all I get is false so...

1. How can I get all of the select data that has been selected and then
2. How to I format it for the text string for the post is it

   ```
   my_array[]=1$my_array[]=2 etc
   ```

thanks in advance for your help

Zen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have the answer!

```
  function callAHAH(method,url, pageElement, callMessage,form_name){
  //window.location = url;

//document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = callMessage;
try{
    req = new XMLHttpRequest(); /* ff */
}
catch(e){
    try{
        req = new ActiveObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); /* some ie */
    }
    catch(e){
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); /*other ie */
        }
        catch(e){
            req = false;
        }
    }
}
req.onreadystatechange = function(){responseAHAH(pageElement);};
 var build_url=window.location.origin;
  var url = "aj_scripts/"+url;
 if(build_url=="http://localhost:8080"){        
    url=build_url+"/pitd_outer/pitd/"+url;
 }
// Check request status
if(method=='POST'){
    req.open("POST",url,true);
  // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var the_data="";

  ///
  var the_form=document.getElementById(form_name);
 //alert(form_name);
for (var i=0;i<the_form.length;i++){
      var the_type = the_form.elements[i].type;
      var value;
      if(the_type !="button"){
          if(the_type =="checkbox"){
                value = the_form.elements[i].checked
                var id= the_form.elements[i].id;     
                the_data+=id;
                the_data+="="+value+"&";
          }else if(the_form.elements[i].hasAttribute('multiple') == true){
              var test_data = "";
              var the_multiples = the_form.elements[i].options;
              if((the_form.elements[i].hasAttribute('getall')==true)&&(the_form.elements[i].getAttribute('getall')=="get_all")){
                  //a multiple select that we need to get all values from and not just those that are selected
                  alert("hi");
                  console.log("inside the_form_elements has attributes");                   
                for(var j=0;j<the_multiples.length;j++){
                  test_data +=  the_form.elements[i].id+"="+the_multiples[j].value+"&";  
                }//end of for var j
              }else{
              //a select list with potentially multiple selections and only want the selected ones
                  for(var j=0;j<the_multiples.length;j++){
                      if(the_multiples[j].selected == true){
                      test_data +=  the_form.elements[i].id+"="+the_multiples[j].value+"&";
                      }//end of if the_multiples                          
                  }//end of for var j
              }//end of the if the_form inner
              test_data=test_data.substring(0,test_data.length-1);//removing the last & symbol 
              the_data +=test_data;
              alert(test_data);

          }else{

                value=the_form.elements[i].value;
                var id= the_form.elements[i].id;     
                the_data+=id;
                the_data+="="+value+"&";
          }//end of if the_form outer


      }     
  }      
  the_data=the_data.substring(0,the_data.length-1);//removing the last & symbol  

// alert(the_data);
  req.send(the_data);       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter
}else if(method=="GET"){
    req.open("GET",url,true);
    req.send(null);
}
}

  function responseAHAH(pageElement){   
var output='';
if(req.readyState == 4){
    if(req.status == 200){          
        output = req.responseText;
        document.getElementById(pageElement).innerHTML = output;            
    }
}
}
```

The important bit of the code is:

```
  if(the_type !="button"){
          if(the_type =="checkbox"){
                value = the_form.elements[i].checked
                var id= the_form.elements[i].id;     
                the_data+=id;
                the_data+="="+value+"&";
          }else if(the_form.elements[i].hasAttribute('multiple') == true){
              var test_data = "";
              var the_multiples = the_form.elements[i].options;
              if((the_form.elements[i].hasAttribute('getall')==true)&&(the_form.elements[i].getAttribute('getall')=="get_all")){
                  //a multiple select that we need to get all values from and not just those that are selected
                  alert("hi");
                  console.log("inside the_form_elements has attributes");                   
                for(var j=0;j<the_multiples.length;j++){
                  test_data +=  the_form.elements[i].id+"="+the_multiples[j].value+"&";  
                }//end of for var j
              }else{
              //a select list with potentially multiple selections and only want the selected ones
                  for(var j=0;j<the_multiples.length;j++){
                      if(the_multiples[j].selected == true){
                      test_data +=  the_form.elements[i].id+"="+the_multiples[j].value+"&";
                      }//end of if the_multiples                          
                  }//end of for var j
              }//end of the if the_form inner
              test_data=test_data.substring(0,test_data.length-1);//removing the last & symbol 
              the_data +=test_data;
              alert(test_data);

          }else{

                value=the_form.elements[i].value;
                var id= the_form.elements[i].id;     
                the_data+=id;
                the_data+="="+value+"&";
          }//end of if the_form outer
```

Essentially I needed to sue the JavaScript hasAttribute function which I know is apparently not supported by every browser but it worked on IE10, and latest builds of FF O and C.

From there I had to use the .options subselect to cycle through each of select options to find the selected ones.

Those checking the code will notice I have a weird condition in there, the hasAttribute('getall') as I have a very weird situation where I needed to get all of the values out of the multiple select regardless of whether or not they had been selected again I know that non-standard attributes are not sup[ported by all browsers but were with the ones I was using.

regards

Zen